# In JavaScript, is there a performance benefit to limiting a var's scope early on in a function?

Tags: javascript, performance, scope

Say I have a function foo that does a lot of work, and has a var bar declared and used only at the beginning.

```
var foo = function () {
    var bar = 1;
    $('#my-el').click(function () {
        bar += 1;
    });

    //...do lots more work. bar is in scope, but no longer used.
};
```

As you can see, the "click" handler references bar, so bar will be persisted in memory regardless of the content of the remainder of foo. However, bar is also still in scope for the remainder of foo. What I want to know is whether there is any performance benefit to using an immediately-invoked function expression to limit bar's scope, as follows.

```
var foo = function () {
    (function () {
        var bar = 1;
        $('#my-el').click(function () {
            bar += 1;
        });
    }());
    //...do lots more work. bar is out of scope.
};
```

Assuming that the overhead of using the immediately-invoked function expression is negligible compared to the overall execution time of foo, does keeping "bar" out of the scope of the remainder of foo improve performance somehow? I'm concerned only with performance here, not var naming clashes or related concerns.

Comment: This is purely micro-optimizing. You wouldn't notice the difference. If you've a working code, and you want to improve its performance, you could ask a question at [http://codereview.stackexchange.com](http://codereview.stackexchange.com).

Comment: Thank you for the comment. So is it your assertion that there is technically a difference, but it's negligibly small?

Comment: If the function call is not optimized-away it's probably even slower. If you really want to know you'll have to test, see e.g.  https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/timeline (but in this instance you certainly won't see a difference)

Comment: It's very theoretical, say you've a bunch of variables in that scope you'll need later in the function, then one more _might_ slow down the execution, but the difference is meaningless. If you've a time intensive task, the first to drop off is jQuery.

Comment: Consider that any set up (memory or time) that the inner function has to do in the second case, the outer function would need to do in the first case. I can just barely strain my imagination to imagine a case where you'll get *marginally* faster environment-record lookups because there's one fewer variable in the environment record, but environment records are probably implemented as hash maps anyway (variable string name => variable), so any improvement is incredibly small.

Comment: Thank you all for your helpful comments! I wasn't hoping to see anything in particular, and I'm not attempting to optimize anything in this manner right now. I know little of the inner workings of programming languages in general, and JavaScript works very differently from the ones that I'm used to using, so these questions are important in improving my understanding of the language. It seems clear that I can expect little to no benefit of doing this, especially considering the cost in readability.